# How do i rewrite all URL's ending in ?p=1 to the URL without that query in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a website with pagination, which chooses the page to display using the 'p' query.

My issue is that

www.example.com/category.html and

www.example.com/category.html?p=1

Are the same content, and are showing as duplicates for SEO purposes, how do i redirect all ?p=1 queries in nginx to their query free counterpart.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `p` argument is contained in the `$arg_p` variable. The `if` statement can be used to test the value of a variable. The actions available in an `if` block are limited (see [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) for details), but a simple `return` statement is allowed.

So the simplest solution would be to obliterate the query string from any URI which contains `p=1`, like this:

```
server {
    ...
    if ($arg_p = 1) {
        return 301 $uri;
    }
    location / { ... }
}
```

Note that `$uri` is the normalised request URI, and is already missing the query string.